# Односоставные и двусоставные предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Грубой ошибкой будет характеристика как ОСП неполного ДСП со сказуемом в 3 лице (такая ошибка встречается редко) или в прошедшем времени. Чаще всего ошибки связаны с характеристиками неполных частей, где субъектом оказывается 1 или 2 лицо:Я не узнал тебя сразу же, потому что не смог вспомнить. Форма прошедшего времени не указывает на лицо так же однозначно, как формы настоящего и будущего времени. - не понял, в чем допускают ошибки.

...потому что не смог вспомнить. - двусоставное неполное или односоставное по их мнению?

Comment: _Грубой ошибкой будет характеристика как ОСП неполного ДСП **со сказуемом**..._ === Правильно: _**со сказуемым.**_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Я не узнал тебя сразу же, **потому что не смог вспомнить.*** - двусоставное неполное или односоставное?..

**Двусоставное неполное.**

.

[**Из Литневской:**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#35)

> При разборе односоставных предложений учащиеся часто допускают
>   различные ошибки.
>
> Первый тип ошибок связан с необходимостью разграничения односоставных
>   и двусоставных неполных предложений... Определенно-личное предложение
>   мы диагностируем по форме главного члена: сказуемое в нем выражено
>   глаголом в форме 1 и 2 лица единственного и множественного числа
>   изъявительного наклонения (в настоящем и в будущем времени), и в
>   повелительном наклонении; производитель действия определен и может
>   быть назван личными местоимениями 1 и 2 лица *я, ты, мы, вы:*
>
> *Иду, иду, а до леса никак не дойду.*
>
> <...>
>
> Поскольку морфологический признак лица представлен у глагола только в
>   указанных формах, **предложения аналогичного значения со
>   сказуемым-глаголом в форме прошедшего времени изъявительного
>   наклонения и условного наклонения считаются двусоставными неполными**,
>   например:
>
> *Шел, шел, но до леса так и не дошел.*
>
> В этом предложении форма сказуемого никак не указывает на
>   производителя действия. Даже если из предыдущего контекста ясно, что
>   производителем действия является говорящий (говорящие) или слушающий
>   (слушающие), предложения или части сложного предложения без
>   подлежащего со сказуемым в прошедшем времени или в условном наклонении
>   **должны быть охарактеризованы как двусоставные неполные, поскольку информация о производителе действия извлекается не из самого
>   предложения, а из предшествующего контекста**, что, собственно говоря,
>   и является показателем неполноты предложения или его части; см. ,
>   например, вторую часть сложного предложения:
>
> *Я бы тебе помог, **если бы знал** как.*